# javascript image 3d rotate with mouse

Tags: javascript, image, 3d, rotation, mouse

I have 200 to 400 images.I am assigning them to images array,then want to roate those image with mouse movement in all direction (Verticle,Horizontal,Diagonal) like this

http://truview.ortery.com/HTMLJavaScript/FlowerRing/HTML5Viewer.html

how to achieve this with understandable code.
Currently I am using 
http://reel360.org/reel
but it's hard to understand it's code.